# How do I access phpmyadmin?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server, phpmyadmin

I get a 403 Forbidden when I try to access my phpmyadmin.

I installed it from the repository and choosed apache2 in the installation progress. The symlink phpmyadmin.conf in conf.d to apache.conf in phpmyadmin folder was created successfully.

I didn't change anything in the conf file, so I should actually be able to access it immediately, shouldn't I?

The /usr/share/phpmyadmin folders owner and group is root:root. Is that correct? Should it have root:www-data so the apache can access it? If this is the case, should I recursively change the group to all files in /usr/share/phpmyadmin?

I basically followed this tutorial: http://paynedigital.com/articles/2011/09/setting-up-and-securing-a-phpmyadmin-install-on-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: Have you read the installation guide for `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Several different guides. They all say, after an installation from the repo it should be accessible.

Comment: Post your research.  Might help if you format your question a little, its sort of hard to read, also helps to know who told you that virtual hosts can be run under a seperate user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I just made a own VirtualHost for pma. Everything worked then. Still thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause of your problem, that apache has no permission to read your phpmyadmin directory, or php file execution isn't set for this directory in apache. In both cases you will need to be able to see that in the apache error.log .

Also you can su to the apache user (probably www-data), and try to get in your phpmyadmin deployment amd read the files. It is a good test to check if it is the problem of your apache permissions.

Comment: When su to www-data I can open /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php as readonly. Should be sufficient right? In the error.log I get the following message for my requests: "client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin"

Comment: For php called by apache, it is OK if you can "cat" the php files. It is clearly apache config problem (denied by _server_configuration_): apache could read this, but doesn't do this, because it believes it shouldn't. Next question: upload a simple .txt file into your phpmyadmin deploy directory, and try to get this with a browser! Goes this? If yes, the problem is somewehre in the php settings. If no, the problem is about the general file reading.

Comment: I can cat as www-data and I can't access a simple .txt file in the same folder as the index.php of pma. So you mean this is probably a problem in the apache2.conf or in the phpmyadmin.conf?